# Magento / CSV import - products aren't visible in shop

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, php-5.6

I need to import products from CSV file and I used the option to import products with images form CSV file. The import was done without any problem/errors. I have all products imported in admin panel, but **products aren't visible in the shop**.

For simple type products I have set up: visibility, availability, categories (all the required fields). Configurable type products also has all the required fields filled up (including is_in_stock). Each product has set is_in_stock 1.

A product shows up in the shop online only when I manually use a sequence:
set up product availability to false -> save it -> set up product availability to true -> save again

What can be a reason of this problem? Or maybe anyone know how to do this for all products automatically / directly via database, not manually?

I also tried this method: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Admin-Configuration/Bulk-update-stock-status/td-p/22130 - without any results.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that in your CSV file you forget to add the **websites**. And check below attributes that you have added or not.if not add and check once.

```
status => Enabled ,
is_in_stock => 1,
visibility => Catalog, Search ,
websites => base,
qty => 10
```

[image]

check the above image for your clarification.

Comment: Thank you!After verifying the export file, it turned out that the "websites" parameter was not set. To change it, just select all products -> select "Update attributes" -> submit -> "Websites" -> select "Add Product To Websites".